# How to send log to JSON web service?

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, logback

I am thinking about the best way to send log information periodically from my android device to the server. So far I have not found any resources on how this is done properly. I already have a server that accepts JSON and can store the log information in SQL. How do I package up the log to send over JSON? I would prefer to send it as a java object. I am using logback-android for logging.

This app will not be published on Google Play and I can't use third party services.

Thanks

Comment: Java objects are a bad idea. Better use a custom light-wight data structure that only contains the necessary fields. BTW: How do you store the log data on Android side?

Comment: @Robert What would be a good light weight data structure?  Currently it's writing to a log file, but I am considering changing it to SQLite

Comment: @Robert do you happen to know how to get the logs out of the SQLite and/or file to parse into a JSON object?

Comment: Perform an SQL query, create an JSON object for each row in the result and add the fields from the database response to the JSON object?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to send JSON I would say just [roll your own appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html). [Logstash](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder) seems to partially do what you need. You have not specified how you communicate with the web service (socket, REST, SOAP, etc). If it is TCP sockets then there are appenders in logstash. If it is REST you can use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

If you use Retrofit you should buffer a list of logging messages and then make a POST request with all of them as you may end up making too many HTTP calls if you use a HTTP request per log line. However if there is a problem you may end up losing a bunch of logging messages. Adjust the size of the buffer to your use case.

Comment: ahh... Logstash seems helpful since it logs in JSON, I will be communicating via REST and I have Retrofit implemented. I just need to send up an array of EventLog objects in json format.

Comment: What kind of Appender should I be using? Like you said I want to have an list of EventLog objects before I send it up to the server. The logs will be sent periodically either every hour, few hours, or day.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a [SocketAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) to send the logging from logback over the network.

You would need a server that can receive data on a TCP socket and then configure logback through logback.xml to use a socket appender.

From the link the logback configuration should look like this:

```
<configuration>
   <appender name="SOCKET" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SocketAppender">
      <remoteHost>${host}</remoteHost>
      <port>${port}</port>
      <reconnectionDelay>10000</reconnectionDelay>
      <includeCallerData>${includeCallerData}</includeCallerData>
   </appender>
   <root level="DEBUG">
      <appender-ref ref="SOCKET" />
   </root>  
</configuration>
```

For the socket server you can roll your own or use whatever is out there. A fairly interesting option would be [Chronicle](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue).

Comment: I want to hook into an existing logging web service that takes in a JSON object. For this reason, SocketAppender won't work for my purposes.